# in php is it the right way to checked a checkbox until the url back to the index page?

Tags: php

my php code of line for checkbox its correct or not to checkbox to be checked.

```
                    <input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" checked />article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal'  checked/>journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <?php } elseif( isset( $_GET['article'] ) ) { ?>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" checked/>article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal' />journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

                <?php } elseif( isset( $_GET['journal'] ) ) { ?>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" />article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal'  checked/>journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <?php } else { ?>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" />article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal'  />journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <?php } ?>
```

right way in php ?? to checked a checkbox for page reload and anchor click ??

Comment: dont understand your problem and question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a play with this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" <?php echo (isset($_GET['article) ? 'checked' : ''); ?> />article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
<input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal' <?php echo (isset($_GET['journal) ? 'checked' : ''); ?> />journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

If article or journal are set then checked will be placed into the input, if not it is left blank.

Comment: bt when i click on pagination it automatically unchecked the checkbox..

Comment: Then the $_GET['article/journal'] is not set when the page changes.  You need to either pass the variable with the page change or store it into a session so that it is always there for you.

Comment: hmm thanx  Blinkydamo understood now ive to use session to take value from one page to another page...

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="article" id='article' value="article" <?php echo (isset($_GET['article) ? 'checked' : ''); ?> />article&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
<input type="checkbox" name="journal" value="journal" id='journal' <?php echo (isset($_GET['journal) ? 'checked' : ''); ?> />journal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  acording to your this code when i click on journal/article it will take the value of selected one is it right???

Comment: Can you provide more of the code you are using so we can try and better understand the issue if this is not solving your problem.